# Cannot access disk, partition table broken

Tags: filesystems, gparted

I was so dumb, to turn of the power on my Readynas Ultra 4 when it was installing the disk (3TB WD Green), I had no time to wait for it as I was going to return it (It was too damn noisy) The disk installation was at 0% and stayed like that for 2 minutes, so I decided to turn it off without really thinking about the consequences. Anyways, now it’s done, and I need to put it into my new NAS (Synology 413j), but that’s not going very good.
The disk is recognized in BIOS, and I get it up as /dev/sdc when I run gparted live on USB. But it is not shown in Windows device manager or in Ubuntu.
When I run sudo gparted on a live Ubuntu USB, I get Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc.

I have tried more stuff in gparted live, but to sum it up, it is very similar to what's happening here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1492414.html
Up to the part where he runs badsectors, and get alot of errors, I ran badsectors -vs (I guess that is just read, and show output. I ran it for about 3000sectors, and for each block it counted the output was: (and so on)

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
140.00% done, 0:01 elapsed. (14/0/0 errors)
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
310.00% done, 0:02 elapsed. (31/0/0 errors)
```

In gparted(live) the /dev/sdc disk shows, but its all unallocated, and it shows an input/output read error when it scans all disks. When I try to create a new partition, I get an error with no partition table. I go to device - create partition table, and select gpt, I get about 5-6 errors with input/output read and also write on /dev/sdc.

When I enter gdisk on gparted(live) I get:

```
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
MBR: not present
BSD: not present
APM: not present
GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.
```

When I run smartctl:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo smartctl --all /dev/sdc
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [x86_64-linux-3.2.0-29-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0
Serial Number:    WD-WCAWZ2205xxxxx
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 25c5f8480
Firmware Version: 80.00A80
User Capacity:    3,000,592,982,016 bytes [3.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Sat Sep 29 15:53:44 2012 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84)    Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0)    The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:         (50700) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:              (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003)    Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01)    Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:      (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:      ( 255) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:      (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:            (0x3035)    SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   199   140   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       7050
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       483
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       572
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       142
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       31
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   198   198   000    Old_age   Always       -       8522
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   114   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       38
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%       569         42084912
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       388         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

My gdisk session under here: But the most usefull I got to in the end:
Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 34 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

```
user@debian:~$ sudo gdisk
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.5

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sdc
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Warning! Read error 5; strange behavior now likely!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries.

Command (? for help): ?
b   back up GPT data to a file
c   change a partition's name
d   delete a partition
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   list known partition types
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
r   recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s   sort partitions
t   change a partition's type code
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Command (? for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-5860533134, default = 2048) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 2048
Last sector (2048-5860533134, default = 5860533134) or {+-}size{KMGTP}: 5860533134
Current type is 'Linux filesystem'
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): l 
0700 Microsoft basic data  0c01 Microsoft reserved    2700 Windows RE          
4200 Windows LDM data      4201 Windows LDM metadata  7501 IBM GPFS            
7f00 ChromeOS kernel       7f01 ChromeOS root         7f02 ChromeOS reserved   
8200 Linux swap            8300 Linux filesystem      8301 Linux reserved      
8e00 Linux LVM             a500 FreeBSD disklabel     a501 FreeBSD boot        
a502 FreeBSD swap          a503 FreeBSD UFS           a504 FreeBSD ZFS         
a505 FreeBSD Vinum/RAID    a580 Midnight BSD data     a581 Midnight BSD boot   
a582 Midnight BSD swap     a583 Midnight BSD UFS      a584 Midnight BSD ZFS    
a585 Midnight BSD Vinum    a800 Apple UFS             a901 NetBSD swap         
a902 NetBSD FFS            a903 NetBSD LFS            a904 NetBSD concatenated 
a905 NetBSD encrypted      a906 NetBSD RAID           ab00 Apple boot          
af00 Apple HFS/HFS+        af01 Apple RAID            af02 Apple RAID offline  
af03 Apple label           af04 AppleTV recovery      af05 Apple Core Storage  
be00 Solaris boot          bf00 Solaris root          bf01 Solaris /usr & Mac Z
bf02 Solaris swap          bf03 Solaris backup        bf04 Solaris /var        
bf05 Solaris /home         bf06 Solaris alternate se  bf07 Solaris Reserved 1  
bf08 Solaris Reserved 2    bf09 Solaris Reserved 3    bf0a Solaris Reserved 4  
bf0b Solaris Reserved 5    c001 HP-UX data            c002 HP-UX service       
ef00 EFI System            ef01 MBR partition scheme  ef02 BIOS boot partition 
fd00 Linux RAID            
Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): ef01
Changed type of partition to 'MBR partition scheme'

Command (? for help): ?
b   back up GPT data to a file
c   change a partition's name
d   delete a partition
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   list known partition types
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
r   recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s   sort partitions
t   change a partition's type code
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdc.
Unable to save backup partition table! Perhaps the 'e' option on the experts'
menu will resolve this problem.
Warning! An error was reported when writing the partition table! This error
MIGHT be harmless, or the disk might be damaged! Checking it is advisable.

Command (? for help): o   
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): Y

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 3995C753-D73D-4386-8818-3A9AF06E3B2C
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5860533101 sectors (2.7 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): Y

Command (? for help): w

Final checks complete. About to write GPT data. THIS WILL OVERWRITE EXISTING
PARTITIONS!!

Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): Y
OK; writing new GUID partition table (GPT) to /dev/sdc.
Unable to save backup partition table! Perhaps the 'e' option on the experts'
menu will resolve this problem.
Warning! An error was reported when writing the partition table! This error
MIGHT be harmless, or the disk might be damaged! Checking it is advisable.

Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 5860533168 sectors, 2.7 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): F1AE4B7D-9CCE-4211-BE3D-88DFFCCD3696
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 5860533134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 5860533101 sectors (2.7 TiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name

Command (? for help): o
This option deletes all partitions and creates a new protective MBR.
Proceed? (Y/N): n

Command (? for help): ?
b   back up GPT data to a file
c   change a partition's name
d   delete a partition
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   list known partition types
n   add a new partition
o   create a new empty GUID partition table (GPT)
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
r   recovery and transformation options (experts only)
s   sort partitions
t   change a partition's type code
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Command (? for help): d
No partitions

Command (? for help): i
No partitions

Command (? for help): r

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b   use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c   load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d   use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e   load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f   load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g   convert GPT into MBR and exit
h   make hybrid MBR
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   load partition data from a backup file
m   return to main menu
o   print protective MBR data
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
t   transform BSD disklabel partition
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): f
Warning! This will destroy the currently defined partitions! Proceed? (Y/N): Y
Problem loading MBR! GPT is untouched; regenerating protective MBR!

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): ?
b   use backup GPT header (rebuilding main)
c   load backup partition table from disk (rebuilding main)
d   use main GPT header (rebuilding backup)
e   load main partition table from disk (rebuilding backup)
f   load MBR and build fresh GPT from it
g   convert GPT into MBR and exit
h   make hybrid MBR
i   show detailed information on a partition
l   load partition data from a backup file
m   return to main menu
o   print protective MBR data
p   print the partition table
q   quit without saving changes
t   transform BSD disklabel partition
v   verify disk
w   write table to disk and exit
x   extra functionality (experts only)
?   print this menu

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): v

No problems found. 5860533101 free sectors (2.7 TiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 5860533101 (2.7 TiB) in size.

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): b

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): c
Warning! This will probably do weird things if you've converted an MBR to
GPT form and haven't yet saved the GPT! Proceed? (Y/N): Y
Warning! Read error 5! Misbehavior now likely!
Caution! After loading partitions, the CRC doesn't check out!

Recovery/transformation command (? for help): w
Warning! Main partition table overlaps the first partition by 34 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Aborting write of new partition table.
```

No matter what I try to do, I seem to get the input/output error, I tried installing Ubuntu on it, and it seems to create the partition table, but when I start the install -- input/output error.

Anyone have any idea on how I can fix this? I’m happy to post more logfiles or whatever, but I’m not experienced with Linux, I just use it for this kind of stuff. The disk is very new, just some months, so I doubt it’s any bad sectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have copy & pasted a lot of unnecessary transcripts but your first paragraph pretty much says it all:

> When I run sudo gparted on a live ubuntu USB, I get Input/output error during read on /dev/sdc.

So you have a defective disk. The error comes directly on `/dev/sdc` (not `/dev/sdc1` or `/dev/sda2`, etc...) so it applies to the whole disk. Therefore the partition table has nothing to do with it.

You should look at the output of `dmesg` or the contents of `/var/log/kern.log` to get additional information about the I/O error. If it's a defective sector then this will tell you which sector it is.

Doing a bad blocks scan with `badblocks -w /dev/sdc` might give you interesting output. It might also force the hard drive's onboard firmware to reallocate bad sectors from its spare sector pool so that you can continue using the drive.

Comment: Thank you for these tips!! Some questions tho: I did not find any kern.log file on that location(from gparted live cd). I found one error about /dev/sdc.

I will post it in a answer since it does not fit here.

Comment: [  322.414717]         72 0b 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00 
[  322.414721]         00 00 00 00 
[  322.414723] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc]  Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[  322.414725] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  322.414729] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 0
[  322.414735] ata4: EH complete

Comment: Your drive has bad sectors.  Get it replaced if it's still under warranty.

Comment: It was bougt just a few months ago, so thats no problem. But it was me who caused those bad sectors :( I guess its better to replace it anyways, If I partly repair it to the point where its usable, they might not accept it with RMA, because it works, but it might not perform as good...? or the disk could be smaller if its alot of sectors?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that merely shutting of the NAS will have damaged the disk.  Doing that may cause filesystem corruption, but not physical damage.  Also, the fact that it was stuck at 0% for 2+ minutes indicates that it was probably already defective (or, as Giles suggested, the drive's power or data cables may be loose or faulty).

Comment: I doubt there was any problems with it from before, a scan like the one started took about 6 hours the first time, so I was probably not stuck at 0%, just took some time. I think I'll try the badblocks -w options. Or any other sugestions?

Answer (score 2):

It's not just that the partition table isn't correct: there is an error when trying to read it. So whatever is wrong isn't due to the aborted installation attempt. That could have left the data on the disk in an inconsistent state, but it wouldn't have made the disk unreadable.

You have a hardware or driver failure. It's probably the disk, but it could be the cable or even the disk controller. Check by unplugging and plugging back the power and data connectors, then plugging the disk into a different machine, preferably with a different cable.

Comment: Thank you for your tips! I checked with another cable with no luck, it cannot be the compuer or the cable as I tested with a cable that worked with another drive.

Comment: Thanks.  after reading through this thread, im convinced that i have bad hard drives, due to fed-ex/ups bad handling most likely.  a box of 8 were shipped to my house.  im getting `I/O` and `async page read` errors, and same gdisk symptoms as OP.  yeppers!!  Crap.  I have to send them back.

Comment: ill have to admit, im still on the fence that this isnt just a locked hard drive on my hands.  Articles like this point out how to fix these types of symptoms https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250602/hard-disk-gpt-header-corrupted  and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=199183 to some extent.