# GParted on USB: Backup GPT Table is Currupt

Tags: linux-mint, partition, gparted, partition-table

I have a new USB and have used it before however when plugging it in, it does not show up on my desktop in Linux Mint.  When opening GParted, a message pops up that says `Libparted Bug Found! The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.` After that, the USB still does not show up on desktop.  So I tried creating a new partition table in GParted yet the same message comes up and when I try to make one, after clicking apply it does nothing.  I have checked out this thread but could not fix my issue:  [Cannot access disk, partition table broken](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49476/cannot-access-disk-partition-table-broken)  Does anybody know the cause of this and how I could fix it?  I am willing to attach any output if necessary.

[image]